# How can I add days to date exist in database in laravel?

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

Let's say I have a table with some date values saved like this:

> 2022-02-02 00:00:00

How can I increase said date after retrieving it from the database?
For example:

```
$importantDates = User::where('has_date', true)->pluck('date');
$increase = 2;
$changedDates = [];
foreach($importantDates as $date)
    $changedDates[] = ...; // add two days to the date
```

if `$date` contains `'2022-02-02'` how can I store `'2022-02-04'` inside `$changedDates` instead?

Comment: Plz add some code ?

Comment: Can you add your code here? Like is it laravel's timestamp? (create_at and/or update_at) or something else?

Are you saving as a timestamp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the date column is carbon object then

```php
$user = \App\User::find(1);
$user->date = $user->date->addDays(1);
$user->save();
```

If the date column is not carbon object then

```php
$user = \App\User::find(1);
$user->date = Carbon::parse($user->date)->addDays(2);
$user->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use Carbon library for that:

```
    $date = Carbon::now();
    $dateInFuture = $date->addDays($numberOfDays);
```

Answer (score 0):

let say you have a date `created_at` as timestamp in your table. you may achieve it by using [mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) instead of doing it manually every time.

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon::parse($value)->addDays(5);
}
```

This will automatically add 5 days to your created_at column whenever your fetch it.

if you don't want to modify that column then what you may do is; in your model class add following lines;

```
protected $appends = ['future'];

public function getFutureAttribute()
{
    return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['created_at'])->addDays(5);
}
```

this will append `future` attribute to your model whenever you query them on eloquent.